# Print all subsets with given sum

Tags: java, recursion

Given an array of integers and a sum, the task is to print all subsets of given array with sum equal to given sum **recursively**.

Input : arr[] = {2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10}

sum = 10

Output :

5 2 3

2 8

10

I have tried something please take a look .my code doesn't produce the right output. On running the code it gives no output but also no errors and warning is shown.I dont know where my approach is wrong in my code.

k is sum

si is starting index

```
public class returnSubsetOfsumK {


private static int[][] subsetsSumK(int input[], int k,int si){      
    //base case
 if(si == input.length ) {
        if(k==0) {
            int ans[][] = {{}};
            return ans;
        }else {
            int ans[][] = {};
            return ans;
        }
    }

    //case 1

    int temp1[][] = subsetsSumK(input, k-input[si], si+1);
    if(temp1.length==0) {
        int ans[][] = {};
        return ans;
    }

    //appending input[si] in output

    int temp3[][] = new int[temp1.length][];

    for(int i = 0;i<temp1.length;i++) {
        temp3[i] = new int[temp1[i].length+1];

    }

    for(int i = 0;i<temp3.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<temp3[i].length;j++) {
            if(j==0) {
                temp3[i][j] = input[si];
            }else {
                temp3[i][j] = temp1[i][j-1];
            }
        }

    }




    //case 2

    int temp2[][] = subsetsSumK(input, k, si+1);

    if(temp2.length==0) {
        int ans[][] = {};
        return ans;
    }


    //Final Output to add temp3 and temp2;
    int output[][] = new int[temp3.length+temp2.length][];

    for(int i = 0;i<temp3.length;i++) {
        output[i] = new int[temp3[i].length];
    }
    for(int i = temp3.length;i<output.length;i++) {
        output[i] = new int[temp2[i-temp3.length].length];
    }


    for(int i = 0;i<temp3.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<temp3[i].length;j++) {
            output[i][j] = temp3[i][j];
       }  
    }

    for(int i = temp3.length;i<output.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<output[i].length;j++) {
            output[i][j] = temp2[i-temp3.length][j];
         }
    }



    return output;
}



public static int[][] subsetsSumK(int input[], int k) {
    // Write your code here
         return subsetsSumK(input, k, 0);

    }





public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int input[] = {2,1,3,2};
    int out[][] = subsetsSumK(input, 4); 
    for(int i = 0;i<out.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<out[i].length;j++) {
            System.out.print(out[i][j]);
         }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It would be easier for us to understand your logic if your variable names were more descriptive than `k` and `si`. But a good starting point would be to figure out how you'd approach the problem on paper and work from there.

Comment: @jsheeran should i edit this question?

Comment: si is starting index and k is sum

Comment: @jsheeran can you please tell me how can i explain you my approach to question?

Comment: Editing your above comment into the question would be fine. Also, for "my code doesn't produce the right output" questions, it's helpful to see the actual output you're getting.

Comment: @jsheeran it shows no output i have edited my question please take a look